# Correo se envía con múltiples copias del mensaje. php mail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

tengo la siguiente Función que se ejecuta al presionar un botón, trae una cantidad de usuarios desde la base de datos y a cada uno le debe enviar un correo que es un recordatorio semanal, el tema es que el primer correo se envía bien pero cada correo posterior en la sección de mensaje se concatena con el correo anterior.

```
public function enviarMensaje2()
{
    $this->load->model('loginm'); 
    $nombres['nombre'] = $this->loginm->TraerDatos($_SESSION['usuarios']);  

    @$link = mysql_connect("*","*","*");
    if(!$link) 
    {
        echo("no se ha podido realizar la conexion a BD, ". mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("*",$link);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                          
    $querymail = "*";
    $querycorres = mysql_query($querymail);


    while($rx = mysql_fetch_array($querycorres)){

    include_once('application/third_party/phpmail/class.phpmailer.php');
    include_once('application/third_party/phpmail/class.smtp.php');
    
    @$asunto = "*";
    @$message = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    @$mensaje .="<html>";
    @$mensaje .="<head>";
    @$mensaje .="<title></title>";
    @$mensaje .="</head>";
    @$mensaje .="<body style='font-family: 'arial';'>";
    @$mensaje .="<div style='width: 100%;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;background: #ffbb38; border-radius: 18px;display:block; float:center;'><h2 style='padding: 15px;color:#b22222; font-weight: bold; text-align: center'>Recordatorio Semanal</h2> </div>";
    @$mensaje .="<div style=''><img style='display:block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' src='estilo/images/semanal/1.jpg' /></div>";
    @$mensaje .="<div style=''><img style='display:block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' src='estilo/images/semanal/2.jpg' /></div>";
    @$mensaje .="<div style=''><img style='display:block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' src='estilo/images/semanal/3.jpg' /></div>";
    @$mensaje .="<div style=''><img style='display:block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' src='estilo/images/semanal/4.jpg' /></div>";
    @$mensaje .="<div >";
    @$mensaje .="</body>";
    @$mensaje .="</html>";
 
    $mail= new PHPMailer() ;   
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.mail.pjud";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    
    $mail->Username ='*l';
    $mail->Password ='*'; 
    
    $mail->AddAddress($rx['emailpjudusuarios']);
    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body = $mensaje;
    $mail->From = "notificador_automatico@pjud.cl";
    $mail->FromName = "1 Juzgado de letras del trabajo de Santiago";
    //Para adjuntar archivo
    $mail->MsgHTML($mensaje);

    if($mail->Send());

        }

        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Notificacion enviada Correctamente");
        </script>';
        redirect('semanal/semanalC/enviar_semanal','refresh');
}
```

En el futuro me gustaria que el correo se envie automaticamente todos los lunes si alguien me puede ayudar con eso igual seria genial. gracias.

Comment: `PHPMailer` trae las funciones `$mail->addCC` _con copia_ y `$mail->addBCC` _con copia oculta_. Intenta pasar el arreglo de correos en estas funciones. Si tienes el mismo resultado, el problema puede ser la manera en que estás pasando los correos.